# Insert primary key and foreign key two tables

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access raw SQL (for database) and PHP. I have two tables:

`table1`: contains columns (user_id, name, email), [user_id is auto increment number ...1,2 etc]

`table2` contains column (product_id, user_id, product, price etc)

When I insert any value on table1 then auto incremented user_id will be generated, in same time for table2 another value I want to will insert with the previous auto incremented user_id from table1 in column (user_id) in table2.

Table1:

```
user_id     name    email
1           jhon    jhon@example.com
2           mary    mary@example.com
3           david   david@example.com
```

Table2:

```
product_id  user_id      product    price
1          1             toy        12 USD
2          1             cleaning   13 USD
3          2             book       14 USD
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a single query. If you are ok with 2 queries then I think `@@identity` holds the last inserted auto incremented id.

Comment: will it work on MS access SQL?

Comment: It should, it's very specific to MS-Access